# java cyrptography BigInteger - Generated prime q to find prime P =2q+1,Complete - Now how to generate and confirm primitive root g?

Tags: java, cryptography, primes

Now that I have generated prime P that is a strong prime, how could I generate a primitive root g?

I believe I'll generate another bigInt for g, then check to see if it is a primitive root.

The generation is easy and I can do it as I do in the Prime p generation.

Checking to make sure it is a primitive root has me a bit stumped.  I need to make sure g^q which is equal to g^((p-1)/2) is not congruent to 1 mod p.  Is there a BigInteger function to handle this?

Wikipedia has euler's theorum as this.  But I'm not sure which is my a and which is my n.  I can use a^phi(n) for this forumla correct?

[image]

```
public void getKey() {
debug("Getting key (seed) from user");

BigInteger primeP;
BigInteger primeQ;
int bitLength = 512;
Random rnd = new Random();
boolean boolPrimeP = false;
boolean boolPrimeQ = false;
int iteration= 0;

while (boolPrimeQ == false || boolPrimeP == false){
    iteration++;
    primeQ = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitLength, rnd);
    boolPrimeQ = primeQ.isProbablePrime(3);
    if (boolPrimeQ==true){
        primeP = primeQ.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
        primeP = primeP.add(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
        boolPrimeP = primeP.isProbablePrime(3);
        if (boolPrimeP==true){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because your prime P has the special form P = 2q + 1, checking for primitivity is easy. Since P-1=2q, pick a g != 1 and If g^2 != 1 and g^q != 1 then g is a primitive root.

Comment: @JamesKPolk, nice insight.  After spending a bit of time verifying the math in your comment, my answer below seems to be from the dark ages. Why don't you add your comment as answer as it is far superior? I would hate for my answer to remain as the primary one. I will gladly upvote it and remove mine so as not to add noise.

Answer (score 1):

Finding primitive roots mod *p* is difficult, especially if *p* is very large.  I'm not sure if there exist a pre-built `GetPrimitive()` function in any java libraries, however following the method below is the best I've encountered (It is the general algorithm outlined on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots)).

You will need to build your own function for fast exponentiation mod *p*. This is generally, a very easy recursion tasks. Below is pseudo code that should get you started:

```
Function FastExpModP(x as int, n as int, p as int) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return(1);
    } else if (n == 1) {
        return(x);
    } else if (n mod 2==0) {
        return(FastExpModP(x^2 mod p, n/2, p));
    } else {
        return(x * FastExpModP(x^2 mod p, (n-1)/2, p)) mod p);
    }
}
```

Next you will have to find all prime numbers that divide *p* - 1 (Not the prime factorization necessarily) since `phi(p) = p - 1`. Assume that the prime factors of *p* - 1 are the following: *p<sub>1</sub>, p<sub>2</sub>, ..., p<sub>k</sub>* (there are several published easy to understand algorithms for performing this task already, so I will leave this out unless requested).

Now all that is required, is to check the modular exponentiation mod *p* of every element (I generally start with the number 2) over all exponents of the form

> (*p* - 1)/*p<sub>i</sub>*, for all 1 <= *i* <= *k*

until you find a result not equal to one for all exponents. Below is pseudo code for this task:

```
Function GetPrimitive(p as int, pfacs[] as int) {
    m = p - 1
    for (int i = 2; i <= m; ++i) {
        for (int q = 1; q <= pfacs.length; ++q) {
            test = FastExpModP(i, m/pfacs[q], p)
            if (test==1) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (test > 1) {
            return(i);
        }
    }
}
```

For example, take the prime number *p* = 28764457. Now, *m* = *p* - 1 and the prime factors of *m* are:

> 2, 3, 7, 131, and 1307

and *m* divided by each of the above prime numbers gives:

> 14382228, 9588152, 4109208, 219576, and 22008

Now, we will iterate from 2, checking the modular exponentiation mod *p* to see if the result for each exponent is equal to 1. We stop once we find a number such that the modular exponentiation mod *p* for each exponent is NOT equal to 1.

```
For 2 we have:
    2^14382228 = 1 mod p ==>> stop... try 3

For 3 we have:
    3^14382228 = 1 mod p ==>> stop... try 4

For 4 we have (same as 2 since 4 = 2^2):
    4^14382228 = 1 mod p ==>> stop... try 5

For 5 we have:
    5^14382228 = 28764456 mod p, 5^9588152 = 13076987 mod p, 5^4109208 = 1 mod p ==>> stop... try 6

For 6 we have:
    6^14382228 = 1 mod p ==>> stop... try 7

For 7 we have:
    7^14382228 = 1 mod p ==>> stop... try 8

For 8 we have (same as 2 since 8 = 2^3):
    8^14382228 = 1 mod p ==>> stop... try 9

For 9 we have (same as 3 since 9 = 3^2):
    9^14382228 = 1 mod p ==>> stop... try 10

For 10 we have:
    10^14382228 = 28764456 mod p, 10^9588152 = 15687469 mod p, 10^4109208 = 23392715 mod p
    10^219576 = 17852870 mod p, 10^22008 = 5014623 mod p ==>> winner!!!
```

Thus, calling the function `GetPrimitive(28764457, {2, 3, 7, 131, 1307})` will return `10` as the smallest primitive root mod *p*.

For more mathematical background on this topic, check out this [mathematics exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124408/finding-a-primitive-root-of-a-prime-number).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to generate a strong prime, or implement an algorithm for checking primality?
A prime *P* is strong, if its closer to the next prime *q*, than to the largest prime *p* smaller than *P*. Mathematically, it means:

P > (p+q) / 2 ; here p is the closest smaller and q the closest grater prime than P.

BigInteger has a method nextProbablePrime. When generated a prime *p*, generate next *P* and then next *q*, and then check, if *P > (p+q)/2*

Here you are trying to generate prime *P* such that P = 2*q - 1, that's not a strong prime, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_prime

> Is there a BigInteger function to handle this?

What do you mean by "this" ? BigInt checks for primility and generates a prime, also can compute a modulo or other arithmetic operations.

> But I'm not sure which is my a and which is my n

Your *n* is that case the number *P*, you are testing for primality.
The *a* is the primitive root used for check, if *P* is prime.

> how could I generate a primitive root g?

Randomly :)

See also Rabin-Miller algorithm.
https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test

Comment: I don't think this really answers the OP's question. OP clearly states that he has already generated a strong prime and wants to find a primitive root of such a number.

Comment: you are right here, but I was confused of the prime generating, because it seems to be safe, not strong, does it?

Comment: Indeed. Nice catch.